# Copying a database inside a fragment then using it in Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite

Code from my databasehelper class.

```
package com.app.testapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private String DB_PATH;
    private static String DB_NAME = "test";
    private final Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
        this.DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";
        Log.e("Database Path:", DB_PATH);
    }

    public void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outString = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outString);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

Code from my viewFragment class

```
package com.app.testapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ViewFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        initDatabase(db);
        return view;
    }

    private void initDatabase(DatabaseHelper db) {
        try {
            db.copyDatabase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Error creating database");
        }
    }

}
```

Code from my MainActivity class.

```
package com.app.testapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag_container, new ViewFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

I am trying to copy a database which is already pre-made and then make a new local database which i can access and use in my program. I have seen code similar to this working before and have code similar to this working with a button however i cant get this to work.

My error is as follows

```
2019-03-17 23:32:46.645 13197-13197/com.app.testapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.app.testapp, PID: 13197
java.lang.Error: Error creating database
    at com.app.testapp.ViewFragment.initDatabase(ViewFragment.java:28)
    at com.app.testapp.ViewFragment.onCreateView(ViewFragment.java:20)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1248)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Additional log :-

```
    E/Database Path:: /data/data/com.app.testapp/databases/
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.app.testapp/databases/test (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:108)
        at com.app.testapp.DatabaseHelper.copyDatabase(DatabaseHelper.java:29)
        at com.app.testapp.ViewFragment.initDatabase(ViewFragment.java:26)
        at com.app.testapp.ViewFragment.onCreateView(ViewFragment.java:20)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1248)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: I could guess at the issue BUT if you uninstall the App and add line `ioe.printStackTrace()` before the line `throw new Error("Error creating database");` and then rerun and then edit your question to include that stack-trace. A guess wouldn't need to be made as the underlying exception would be shown rather than  the uninformative ***Error creating database***.

Comment: i think i have just added what you have asked for, otherwise i am not to sure

Comment: As guessed. Answer on it's way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few issues.

First, I believe that it does not cater for the installation of the App as new App when the **databases** directory into which the database file will reside doesnn't exist and thus the copy will fail as the output file cannot be opened.

Secondly an attempt will be made to copy the database every time the App is run as there is no check to see if the database actually exists.

Although not really an issue, if the Context's **getDatabasePath** method is used, there is no need to hard code the path, which may be incorrect. It should also future-proof the code.

I believe the following DatabaseHelper would overcome your issues (except if the issue is that the file **test** has been copied into the **assets** folder (and is a valid database)) :-

## DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private String DB_PATH;
    private static String DB_NAME = "test";
    private final Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
        this.DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath(); //<<<<<<<<<< REPLACES following line
        //this.DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";
        Log.e("Database Path:", DB_PATH);
        if (!checkDatabase()) {
            try {
                copyDatabase();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
                throw  new RuntimeException("Error creating Database - see stack-trace above.");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDatabase() {
        File dbpath = new File(DB_PATH);
        if (dbpath.exists()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if (!dbpath.getParentFile().exists()) { 
                dbpath.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void copyDatabase() throws IOException { // MADE PRIVATE AS USED INTERNALLY
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outString = DB_PATH;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outString);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

- Basically the addition of the **checkDatabase** method, which will create the **databases* folder if it doesn't exist, is the fix of the issue you have encountered.

Calling **checkDatabase** before doing the copy and only doing the copy if the database doesn't exists, fixes the second issue that you would have encountered after resolving the first.

- Note that just instantiating the DatabaseHelper will perform the copy of the database file from the assets folder, if needed, therefore your code in the fragment could be

:-

```
public class ViewFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        return view;
    }
}
```